# JGo library. Is it possible to change the icon of the port?

Tags: java, swing

I am using JGo library. Exactly I mean this project http://www.nwoods.com/components/java/jgo-overview.htm.

My question is if it is possible to change the icon of the port inside a node.

For example I am using `JGoBasicNode` and I would like to change the circle inside which is the default node port shape for some icon/ picture. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found the answer. It's possible by calling:

```
JGoPort port = new JGoPort(new Rectangle(new Dimension(10, 10)), image);
setPort(port);
```

where image is an `JGoImage` object